# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore failing on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore, macos-sierra

When I call NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore's synchronize method after running my app directly from Xcode on macOS Sierra, it returns false and following error is printed in Console.app:

> Refusing TCCAccessRequest for service kTCCServiceUbiquity from client
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode in background session

As far as I can tell, changed keys are not saved to iCloud. They are remembered in memory locally but lost after app re-launch.

I believe all my entitlements are set correctly (iCloud KVS enabled in Capabalities of the project, all checked). Do I need to archive & export my app in order to debug / test iCloud on macOS?

Any ideas how to fix / workaround this?

Comment: same problem here, as Sierra is now GM it would be time to fix this by apple

Answer (score 1):

Apple DTS has confirmed that this is an issue on Apple's side and they are working on that.

**Update:** Problem has been solved in macOS 10.12.1

Comment: Thanks! Any link to this issue on Apple website/forum so we can track progress?